# можно ли функции php хранить в отдельном файле и обращаться к ним через код html

Tags: php, html, onclicklistener

Можно ли функции php хранить в отдельном файле php и обращаться к ним через код html, как привязывается к html странице файл scripts.js. Например, нажатие кнопки (onclick) должно вызвать код php из этого файла для работы с базой данных.

Comment: Одно дело вызвать серверный скрипт (что можно) при нажатии кнопки, а другое - это видеть сам скрипт а-ля JS (это нельзя). Серверный скрипт можно вызывать посредством технологии AJAX, либо стандартными методами вроде формы или ссылки на него. А вообще-то лучше вам привести хоть какой-то пример для точности понимания вашего вопроса.

Comment: @Андрей Обратите внимание: HTML и включенный в него JS код выполняется на устройстве пользователя, в браузере. А PHP код выполняется на стороне сервера. И что бы выполнился любой PHP код в ответ на действие на клиенте должен быть произведен запрос по сети ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напрямую вызвать код php через нажатие кнопки нельзя. Это две разные стороны веба - серверная и клиентская. Чтобы здесь не расписываться, советую Вам изучить как вообще работает привычный нам интернет и браузеры. (Вот кратенький ответ https://qna.habr.com/q/112643)
А для начала можете запомнить: PHP, MySQL, Apache - это серверная часть, а HTML, CSS, JS - клиентская. Просто так они никак не связываются, исходя просто из идеи их создания.
Единственный способ реализовать то, что Вам нужно - использовать AJAX, но это требует знаний JavaScript. Можете почитать об этом в интернете, информации очень много, и она несложная.